# Release resources MemoryStream in .NET

Tags: c#, .net

This is a simple code similar on code, which I use in project:

```
MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream();
using (Mp3FileReader reader = new Mp3FileReader(@"C:\Users\practice\Desktop\111.mp3"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Reader");
    Console.ReadLine();
    using (WaveStream waveStream = WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream(reader))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("waveStream");
        Console.ReadLine();
        using (WaveFileWriter waveFileWriter = new WaveFileWriter(outputStream, waveStream.WaveFormat))
        {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[waveStream.Length];
            waveStream.Position = 0;
            waveStream.Read(bytes, 0, (int)waveStream.Length);
            waveFileWriter.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            waveFileWriter.Flush();
            outputStream.Position = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("MAIN STREAM");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}                

outputStream.Dispose();
Console.WriteLine("MAIN STREAM DISPOSE");
Console.ReadLine();
```

As you can see, I write some bytes to `outputStream`. Problem: after Dispose() I can see in `Task Manager`, that resources is not free. How can I clean heap memory of outputStream? I've tried just `using` but I've got the same result.

Comment: Did you try putting MemoryStream in a using statement?

Comment: Task Manager is not an appropriate .NET memory profiler.  Simply run this code many thousands times to feel better about it.  Or use a real profiler.

Comment: MemoryStream has no unmanaged resources. It just uses an array as a backing store which is not released when Dispose is called, it is only reclaimed by garbage collection. You can still retrieve it after calling Dispose using `ToArray()` or `GetBuffer()`.

Comment: `GC.Collect();` - [#DontActually](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2004/11/29/271829.aspx)

Comment: Guys, I've checked using VS Analyzer. And I've got the same result. But how can I collect memory?

Comment: You shouldn't, not unless it's an actual issue, and then, make sure it's an actual issue. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2004/11/29/271829.aspx

Answer (score 1):

First, you should use your `MemoryStream` (or any IDisposable object) in an `using` statement, which is a syntactic sugar for a try/finally block.

```
using(MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream())
using (Mp3FileReader reader = new Mp3FileReader(@"C:\Users\practice\Desktop\111.mp3"))
{
    // code
}
```

Second, calling Dispose in an MemoryStream closes the stream and the handle will be released. It does not mean the memory will be freed immediately. That's a job for the garbage collection.

Comment: Well... putting a `MemoryStream` object in a `using` block is kind of pointless, even though you should definitely do it for other kinds of streams.